# What is the equivalent F# code of a property returning IEnumerable<object[]>

Tags: f#

I am *very* new (yet *very* excited) in F#.

What is the equivalent F# code of a property returning `IEnumerable<object[]>`?

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> EnumerateFooBar
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[]
        {
            "foo", 
            "bar"
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent to C# iterator method in F# is the `seq { .. }` block. This is an expression, so you can use it to define methods (but also inline sequences). Inside the block, you can use `yield` (which corresponds to `yield return` in C#) and you can also use `yield!` to return all elements of a given sequence.

The expression that creates an array `object[]` can be translated to an object literal `[| ... |]` but we need to make sure that the values are returned as objects. This can be done either by adding type annotation or by adding explicit boxing using the `box` function:

Your C# code looks like a read-only property which can be translated as just a value declaration using `let`:

```
let EnumerateFooBar = seq { yield [| box "foo"; box "bar" |] }
```

An alternative using type annotations:

```
let EnumerateFooBar : seq<obj[]> = seq { yield [| "foo"; "bar" |] }
```

And if you wanted to define this as a property of some object:

```
type FooBarEnumerator() = 
  member this.EnumerateFooBar : seq<obj[]> = seq { yield [| "foo"; "bar" |] }
```